# Acumatica Redirect on Page Load prompting an alert of the script

Tags: javascript, c#, acumatica

As per the [Blog](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/06/redirect-on-page-load.html), I have tried redirecting to an external url when a particular sitemap is clicked.

It works well, but there is an alert of the script showing before it redirects to the specified link.

in the page load i have added the below code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;        
        String reporturl = "Some URL";

            String url = string.Format("{0}/?BaseUrl={1}&User={2}&Company={3}", reporturl
                                                                              , HttpUtility.UrlEncode(baseURL)
                                                                              , HttpUtility.UrlEncode(PXAccess.GetUserLogin())
                                                                              , companyid);

            Boolean iscallback = context.Request.Form["__CALLBACKID"] != null;
            Boolean isget = String.Equals(context.Request.HttpMethod, "GET",
                                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Boolean ispost = String.Equals(context.Request.HttpMethod, "POST",
                                StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

            context.Response.Clear();
            if (iscallback)
            {
               context.Response.Write("eRedirect0:" + url);
            }
            if (isget || ispost)
            {  
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.Write("<script language=javascript>");
                context.Response.Write(String.Format("window.open(\"{0}\",\"{1}\");", url, "main"));
                context.Response.Write("</script>");
            }
            context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
            context.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
            context.Response.End();


    }
```

When i click the SiteMap, it automatically prompts an alert as below before it redirects. How to stop this alert?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code resolved the issue.

> **else** if (isget || ispost)

```
if (iscallback)
            {
               context.Response.Write("eRedirect0:" + url);
            }
            else if (isget || ispost)
            {  
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.Write("<script language=javascript>");
                context.Response.Write(String.Format("window.open(\"{0}\",\"{1}\");", url, "main"));
                context.Response.Write("</script>");
            }
```